# Location of configuration in unix program

Tags: unix

I want to write a unix/linux program, that will use a configuration file.

My problem is, where should I put the location of the file?

I could "hardcode" the location (like `/etc`) into the program itself.

However, I would like it, if the user without privileges could install it (through make) somewhere else, like `~`.

Should the makefile edit the source code? Or is it usually done in a different way?

Comment: See the FileSystem Hierarchy Standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for guidance on where things should go, according to convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use a series of places to get the location:

1. Supplied by the user as a command line argument (i.e. `./program -C path/to/config/file.cfg`).
2. From an environment variable (`char *path_to_config = getenv("PROGRAMCONFIG");`).
3. Possibly look for a user specific or local version (`stat("./program.cfg")` or build up a strig to specify either "$HOME/.program/config.cfg" or "$HOME/.program.cfg" and `stat` that).
4. Hardcoded as a backup (`stat("/etc/program/config.cfg",...)`).

Answer (score 6):

Create some defaults:

- `/etc/appname`
- `~/.appname`

Then if you want to allow these to be overridden have your application inspect an environment variable. e.g.

- `$app_userconfig`
- `$app_config`

Which would contain an override path/filename.

Lastly add a command line option that allows a config to be specified at runtime, e.g.

- `-c  |  --config    {filename}`

Answer (score 1):

keeping a global config file under /etc/prgname is a standard.  Also allowing a .local config file for individual users that will override the global settings would allow each user to personalize the program to their preference.

Answer (score 0):

As skaffman says, the canonical locations for things like config files are specified in FHS.  There appears to be a convention that a program will read a config file from the directory from which it is run as an alternative to the one in the hard-coded location.  You may wish to consider adding a command-line switch that allows a user to specify an alternative config file location, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile shouldn't modify the source directly, but it can pass a folder path/name to the compiler through the `-D` option.  One way to handle it would be to #define something like DEFAULT_PATH to be the default installation path.  If the user wants to define a path, the makefile would add `-DUSER_PATH=whatever` to the compiler options.  You would write your code to use USER_PATH if it exists, and DEFAULT_PATH otherwise.